# DynamoDB Query: ScanIndexForward not working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

Quick one I hope.  I have a GSI on a table with a pk (composite string CAMP#g56gd-6…) and a sk (timestamp 166637384).  When I apply `ScanIndexForward` to the query as `true`, it always returns the results in descending order.

Also a side issue is it doesn't seem to set the applied `Limit` to the results.  Always returns the full list of matched items.  Any ideas?

```
const campaignIdParams: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput = {
  TableName: Table.CAMPAIGNS,
  IndexName: TableIndexes.CAMPAIGNS.skCreatedAt,
  KeyConditionExpression: 'sk = :sk',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':sk': parsedSK,
  },
  ProjectionExpression: 'pk',
  ScanIndexForward: sortDir.localeCompare('<') === 0 ? false : true,
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'TOTAL',
  Limit: +limit
}
```

Comment: How is your timestamp sort column formatted? Can you provide sample examples? What datatype is the sk attribute.

Comment: Sure @Stagg timestamps are a Unix timestamp (number) and the sk (pk for the index) is a composite string ‘CAMP#ei8js-he86b-b87j-8778fb’